# MVC5 EF6 Seed Method: Cannot insert NULL into column 'Id' table AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Entity Framework 6, MVC5, ASP Identity 2.0.

I have followed this 2 tutorials to create the login part of the web application:  [part 1](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1) - [part 2](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2)

I created my own AppUser class from IdentityUser Class in another library project. I also have my data context from the IdentityDbContext

```
    public class DataContext: IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
       public DataContext(): base("DefaultConnection") { }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(u => u.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      }
    }

public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [Display(Description = "Email")]
    public override string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Range(0,9999)]
    [Display(Name = "Extension")]
    public int PhoneExtension { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the seed method I get the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'CRM1.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is the seeding method:

```
protected override void Seed(CRM.DAL.Data.DataContext context)
    {
        context.AccessLevels.AddOrUpdate(al => al.Label,
            new Model.AccessLevel { AccessLevelID = 1, Label = "Admin", Description = "Full access to the CRM data" },
            new Model.AccessLevel { AccessLevelID = 2, Label = "Customer Service", Description = "Full access to the CRM data" },
            new Model.AccessLevel { AccessLevelID = 3, Label = "Sales", Description = "Full access to the CRM data" }
            );

        if (!(context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == "admin@admin.com")))
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<AppUser>(context);
            var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(userStore);
            var userToInsert = new AppUser
            {
                Id = "1",
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                Title = "Administrator",
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                PhoneExtension = 0,
                IsActive = true,
                AccessLevelID = 1,
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
                TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                LockoutEnabled = false,
                AccessFailedCount = 0,
                UserName = "admin"
            };
            userManager.Create(userToInsert, "password");
        }

    }
```

So Id gets a value but EF says it is inserting NULL. I tried by not giving any value to Id thinking EF would do it automatically but no.

What is the approach to seed an AspNetUser with my context? I saw different tutorials but it does not apply to my extended AppUser class and DataContext.

Thank you

Comment: Try changing the type of the Id to int and see what happens

Comment: Can you confirm that the `Id` column has been created as an identity column?

Comment: @kkkkk Changing Id to int says that it does not match the type of inherited Id from IdentityUser

Comment: @markpsmith Id is not created as an identity column when looking in the schema of the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().Property(u => u.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

and also this part from your `User`:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Key]
public override string Id { get; set; }
```

You don't need to override this property, just use the parent's property (entity framework will map it).

**Explanation:** when you configure the `Id` property like your did, you're telling entity framework the property value comes from database, so it totally ignores the value you passed to this property when inserting into database.

On the other hand, if your column inside your database table does not have a default value, it will fails, because entity framework is not providing a value for it.

So you need to decide: either your table must have a default value, or you should remove that `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption` option for that field.

The thing is that `IdentityUser` uses a `string` as key, which normally would be a `Guid`. Since EF won't generate `Id` for you automatically, and your column won't as well, you can create a `constructor` to your `User` do like this:

```
public AppUser()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Whenever you create a new user, it will have a new `Guid` as Id....when you read an existing user from your context, although your constructor will generate it when being instantiated by EF, EF will then load `Id` value from your table over it (ignoring the one provided in constructor).

This means the autogenerated Guid inside your constructor will be used only for new instances.

Comment: I tried removing that line only and I get the same result. So I also did remove the overwrite of the Id field in the AppUser because I was using the attribute on it. Then it worked. In the future, from the front end, is EF going to generate the  Id automatically?

Comment: @Greg No, it won't, but I edited my answer with a possible solution for your case.

Comment: For some reason i tried to run the seed method without giving an Id to my user to insert and EF gave me '3a66c954-393f-42e2-b810-36a044d7a0b2' ..... so i did not use the Id = Guid.NewGuid().Tostring(). Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting info. It looks `IdentityUser` generates it for you (not EF at all), although this is from AspNet.Core, I think it's been like this before: [https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat/IdentityUser.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5480aa182bad3fb3b729a0169d0462873331e306/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat/IdentityUser.cs)

Answer (score 3):

The following happened to me. I followed this guide to change the Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity from Guid to Int.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

I had already made some migrations so EF tried to change the Id from nvarchar(128) to int. This worked but `Identity Specification` never turned from No to Yes. Solved it by removing all previous migrations, removing the database and then make a new migration for all the changes. Since we were early in development this was not a problem to do.

[image]